# app engine https spdy

Tags: google-app-engine, https, spdy

i'm using https on appengine. i checked not all request are using https spdy in firefox.  Is there any thing that need to configure so that all requests are using spdy ?

[image]?

Answer (score 5):

As long as the file is served over **https** and by appengine servers, then it will be served over SPDY -- if the browser supports SPDY that is. Can't tell from your screenshot.. but if any of those files come from a different origin (ex, a third party widget), then those files may be served over plain HTTPS if they don't support SPDY.

Comment: all files that you see in the screenshot are from same appengine servers. Any idea why it is not served as https spdy ?

Comment: Most likely because your code is specifically referring to `http://` resources in the markup. You should either switch to `https://` prefixes, or use protocol relative URI's, aka: `//hostname.com`